# Can I get the users location from an iphone webapp?

Tags: iphone

I would like to show a map of things near an iphone user's location. Is there any way to get the latitude/longitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean from within the Safari browser on the device?  I believe it supports the [W3C Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).  Additionally, the Safari developer library has [information on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/GettingGeographicalLocations/GettingGeographicalLocations.html).  I don't know if the two are overlapping or mutually exclusive (I haven't tried), but at least one should work.